# show iframe inside another frame

Tags: html

I need to create html-document where half of the page(on the left) - list of hyperlinks(`Lab2.6-Giper.html`). On the right there are two frames(up and down). In the up frame I show pages from list, in the down frame I need to show iframe with some page(`Lab2.7-Giper_ris.html`).
But It didn't show me iframe. What's the problem?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<frameset cols="50%,*">
    <frameset>
        <frame name="left" src="Lab2.6-Giper.html" target="frame_left_up">
    </frameset>
    <frameset rows="50%,*">
        <frame name="frame_right_up">
        <frameset>
            <iframe name="frame_right_down" src="Lab2.7-Giper_ris.html">Frame</iframe>
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frameset can contain only frames (and other framesets).

If you want an iframe, then you must specify a frame which loads an HTML document. That HTML document may contain an iframe.